# Multiple entries in to table variable using Output INTO clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My use case is as below  :

```
Create table Emp
(
    id int ,
    fname varchar(100),
    lname varchar(100)
)

declare @aud table (prop varchar(1000),[oldval] varchar(100),[toval] varchar(100))

INSERT INTO EMP(id, fname, lname)
OUTPUT 'fname', '', inserted.fname INTO @aud (prop, [oldval], [toval])
VALUES (1,'malcolm','dsouza')


SELECT * FROM @aud
```

I want the data to be formed like:

```
prop   oldval   toval
------------------------
fname           malcolm
lname           dsouza
```

I know we cannot have have multiple inserts using `OUTPUT INTO` clause, but is there any other way I can form a data for inserted rows as column based?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try below steps:

1. OUTPUT clause simply inserts the rows in to the table variable i.e., one row to one row mapping. You need to modify your table definition accordingly.
2. Now, You can use CROSS APPLY to get the result you want.

```sql
**TEST SETUP**
Create table  #Emp(
id int ,
fname  varchar(100),
lname varchar(100)
)
```

**TEST**

```sql
declare @aud table(oldfname varchar(100),fname varchar(100),oldlname varchar(100), lname varchar(100));

INSERT INTO #EMP(id,fname,lname)
OUTPUT '' as oldfname,inserted.fname, '' as oldlname, inserted.lname INTO @aud
values (1,'malcolm','dsouza');

SELECT property, oldval, newval as oldValue  
FROM @aud
CROSS APPLY 
( values('fname',oldfname,fname),('lname',oldlname, lname)) as t(property,oldVal, newVal)
```

**Result Set**

```
+----------+--------+----------+
| property | oldval | oldValue |
+----------+--------+----------+
| fname    |        | malcolm  |
| lname    |        | dsouza   |
+----------+--------+----------+
```